# Passing arrays of varying size to setters/functions in Php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, function, setter

I am relatively new to PHP and have searched quite extensively but can't quite figure out the solution to my problem.

I am trying to figure out how to use setters in a class where the variable being set is an array of an unknown size. For example:

```
class Shirt 
{   
    private $sizes=array();

    public function setSizes($x) 
    {
        $this->sizes=array($x);
    }

}

$BlueShirt = new Shirt;
$BlueShirt -> setSizes (12,14,16);
```

The above code will only set the first size declared in the $BlueShirt object. In some cases shirt objects will have 3 sizes, others may have 3 or 4 and again others may have only 1. I know a simple solution would be to declare the array() in the object:

```
class Shirt 
{      
    private $shirts;

    public function setShirt($x); 
    {
        $this->shirts=($x);
    }
}

$BlueShirt = new Shirt;
$BlueShirt -> setShirt(array(12,14,16));
```

However, I really prefer not to go that route. I use this initial size data in other functions that return size ranges, etc. These functions require that the size data be in array form. I would much rather force the array as even with clear commenting, it may not be obvious to future users adding objects that objects with only one size should still be entered as an array.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: using `setSizes(12,14,16)` there are three function args (which could be retrieved as an array) but not a single function argument as a list: `setShirt(array(12,14,16))`; I would use the latter one;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about :

```
class Shirt {

    private $sizes=array();

    public function setSizes() {
        $this->sizes=func_get_args();
    }

}

$BlueShirt = new Shirt;
$BlueShirt -> setSizes (12,14,16);
```

func_get_arg() get all the args passed to the function. But I don't understand why you don't want to directly give an array to the function.

Comment: that's `func_get_args()` =)

Comment: @ROMMEL thanks for the clarification, works perfectly. Pyrech thanks a ton, solved the issue! There are many many objects, a large number of which with only 1 value in the array. I will not be populating all of the objects myself and can forsee forgetting "array()" on those objects to be a major nuisance issue.

Answer (score 2):

The size of an array doesn't matter in PHP, they can be of any size and can grow as required. Therefore, your question title doesn't really make sense. I suspect that what you want to do is to ensure that an array is always passed to your `setSizes()` function.

You can force parameters to be an array by using type hinting:-

```
class Shirt 
{
    private $sizes=array();

    public function setSizes(array $x) 
    {
        $this->sizes = $x;
    }
}

    $BlueShirt = new Shirt();
    $BlueShirt->setSizes(array(12,14,16));
```

Then, if you mistakenly try to pass a scalar you will get a warining from your IDE and a run time error if you try to run the code.

You can also test for an array and create one if one isn't passed:-

```
class Shirt 
{
    private $sizes=array();

    public function setSizes($x) 
    {
        if(is_array($x){
            $this->sizes = $x;
        } else {
           $this->sizes = array($x);
    }
}

    $BlueShirt = new Shirt();
    $BlueShirt->setSizes(12); //Shirt::sizes will still be an array.
```

Comment: Tried to clean up the code and the title a bit. Interesting test/create. My concern would be there is if 2 sizes were mistakenly not input as an array, then it would only capture the first value. I don't see too much downside to the =func_get_args above so chose that as my ideal answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mjs I'm glad you have a solution, although I personally think that type hinting is a clearer, more readable solution that will show up in  any decent IDE.